# Add "play" button to tosRus lightbox pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

Can you help me out with adding a "play" button to a lightbox using the tosRus lightbox script?

I've made a jsbin here as a concept [jsbin lightbox](http://jsbin.com/gijijonite/edit?html,output)

the tosRus js ligthbox supports autoplay (link to tosrus [tosRus js](http://tosrus.frebsite.nl/configuration.php) and it's possible configuration options.

What I'm trying to do is to have a Play button/link when the lightbox shows up and onClick it should fire the autoplay option

So I thought of doing something like this for the play function:

```
$('.play').on('click',function() {

    $('#xmpl3').tosrus({
        autoplay: {
            play: true
        }
    });

});
```

And the following for the button code:

```
<button class="play">Play</button>
```

and it kind of works as you can see in the jsbin, but the play button should only be showing up when the lightbox pops up. How can you do that?

Comment: This slider not support don't have feature like that. What you can do is a trick. Create <button class='play-button'></div> then configure go-next button in tosrus config and then.

$button.on('click', function () {
   setInterval(function () {
      $('.play-button').click();
  }, 1000);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the play button in the caption. You can place it where you would like in the modal by replacing the following selector `$('.tos-caption')`.

```
var tos = $('#xmpl3 a').tosrus({
    buttons: false,
    caption: {
        add: true
    },
    pagination: {
        add: true,
        type: 'thumbnails'
    },
    slides: {
        scale: 'fill'
    }

});

tos.bind("opening.tos", function( event ) {
    console.log('open');
    $('.tos-caption').append("<button class='play'>Play</button>");
    $('.play').on('click',function() {
        $('#xmpl3').tosrus({
            autoplay: {
                play: true
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://output.jsbin.com/wawuxo/3/

Comment: hi there Esko, thanks for your answer, now the autoplay works only if the lightbox is closed, so it autoplays the thumbs. I wonder, would it be possible to have the images inside the lightbox being autoplayed when you click the play button?

Comment: The Autoplay option you mentioned in the question is not to auto slide the lightbox but autoplay the thumbs. This plug-in does not have the option to rotate images when the lightbox is open. That why there is no example on their site http://tosrus.frebsite.nl/examples.php. The question you asked has been answered. Please provide votes.